# UITableView tableFooterView off screen for iOS6?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a view containing a UITableView. On view did load, I set the table's tableFooterView to be a view I create by hand (a UIView containing a button). When the view appears, I adjust the frame of the tableFooterView:

```
CGRect tableFrame = self.myTableView.frame;
CGRect originalFrame = self.tableFooter.frame;
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(40.0f, 40.0f);
CGRect footerFrame = CGRectMake(originalFrame.origin.x, originalFrame.origin.y, tableFrame.size.width, imageSize.height);
self.tableFooter.frame = footerFrame;
CGRect nextFrame = CGRectMake((footerFrame.size.width - imageSize.width) / 2.0f, 0.0f, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
self.tableFooterButton.frame = nextFrame;
```

On iOS7, this works the way I want -- when I scroll to the bottom of the table, I see my footer view. On iOS6, when I scroll to the bottom of the table, the footer view is still offscreen (I can pull the scroll view and see it, but it resets offscreen when I release).

What should I do differently?

Comment: Try it after you change table footer 's frame . `self.myTableView.tableFooterView = nil; self.myTableView.tableFootView = self.tableFooter`.

Comment: @KudoCC That works. Thanks! Care to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After change the frame of table footer, try this:

```
self.myTableView.tableFooterView = nil ;
self.myTableView.tableFooterView = self.tableFooter ;
```

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal If we change tableFooter's frame, the tableView may be not aware of that, so its contentSize won't change properly. What the code does is reseting the tableView's tableFooterView, so UITableView will arrange its content accordingly.

Comment: I didn't need to use the first line (setting to nil).